# Header reappear on Scroll Up only when it reaches the top

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code that I adapted from another stackoverflow post (which I mention mostly to point out that I know very little about jquery) that makes my header disappear on scroll down and reappear on scroll up. It works perfectly fine BUT I would like the header to reappear on scroll up only when it starts to reach the top again instead of reappearing immediately after scroll up begins.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arminvit/jxfy92n2/2/)

I was able to modify the position — 250 (on code below) — when the header first disappears and I would love to make the header reappear when it reaches that 250 mark.

```
setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you know that the `250` in your posted code is a number of milliseconds not a position.

Comment: Ha! No, I had no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to appear only when totally scrolled back up, change your condition to the following

```
// Scroll Up
if(st === 0) {
    $('header,#body-nav,#body-search').removeClass('header-up').addClass('header-down');
}
```

If you want it to appear opposite of when you hide the header, you could make the condition like this

```
if(st < navbarHeight) {
   ...
```

Comment: Awesome. The second option did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!